# Delete XML node based on position in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML file like this:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <c>1<c/>
    <d>2<d/>
    <e>3<e/>
  </B>
  <B>
    <c>11<c/>
    <d>22<d/>
    <e>33<e/>
  </B>
</A>
```

Say I wanted to delete the second  node.  How would I do this?

I have not written code to do this yet. I've researched online but was not able to find just what I'm looking to do.  My program lists the items in a jtable and it needs to let you select the item and hit a delete button.

I've implemented everything except the deletion, but there is too much and nothing really relevant.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: which second node, do you mean the second <B> node? It really depends on what parser you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it with the XPath expression `/A/B[2]`.

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression compiledExp = xPath.compile("/A/B[2]");
Node foundNode = (Node)compiledExp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

then use:

```
foundNode.getParentNode().removeChild(foundNode);
```

to delete it

Comment: I'm actually getting conflicting types with that.

Comment: There were a couple issues, which I've now fixed